# Text is not fitting inside a replacement span in android

Tags: android, background-color, spannablestring

I want to create a custom background around a block of text. For that, I have come up with a replacement span. Everything was right but the background color is not correctly fitting up with each text. line spacing between each text is 48dp. If I increase the spacing, then the span color is increasing and vice versa. Currently, it seems like the bottom portion of the background fills until the starting of the next line.

This is the code I'm using:
public class CoolBackgroundColorSpan extends ReplacementSpan {

```
private final int mBackgroundColor;
private final int mTextColor;
private final float mCornerRadius;
private final float mPaddingStart;
private final float mPaddingEnd;
private final float mMarginStart;
```

//  private float mheight;

```
public CoolBackgroundColorSpan(int mBackgroundColor, int mTextColor, float mCornerRadius, float mPaddingStart, float mPaddingEnd, float mMarginStart) {
    super();
    this.mBackgroundColor = mBackgroundColor;
    this.mTextColor = mTextColor;
    this.mCornerRadius = mCornerRadius;
    this.mPaddingStart = mPaddingStart;
    this.mPaddingEnd = mPaddingEnd;
    this.mMarginStart = mMarginStart;
}

@Override
public int getSize(@NonNull Paint paint, CharSequence text, int start, int end, @Nullable Paint.FontMetricsInt fm) {
   return (int) (mPaddingStart + paint.measureText(text.subSequence(start, end).toString()) + mPaddingEnd);
}

@Override
public void draw(@NonNull Canvas canvas, CharSequence text, int start, int end, float x, int top, int y, int bottom, @NonNull Paint paint) {
    float width = paint.measureText(text.subSequence(start, end).toString());
    RectF rect = new RectF(x - mPaddingStart + mMarginStart, top, x + width + mPaddingEnd + mMarginStart, bottom);
    paint.setColor(mBackgroundColor);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, mCornerRadius, mCornerRadius, paint);
    paint.setColor(mTextColor);
    canvas.drawText(text, start, end, x + mMarginStart, y, paint);
}
```

I have used LineHeightSpan. But this background color has a movement. This will move to the corresponding text below with each interval of time, like in karaoke. So that time, the line heigth is also increasing.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one has answered yet, I'll post the answer

public void draw(@NonNull Canvas canvas, CharSequence text, int start, int end, float x, int top, int y, int bottom, @NonNull Paint paint) {
float width = paint.measureText(text.subSequence(start, end).toString());
RectF rect = new RectF(x - mPaddingStart + mMarginStart, top, x + width + mPaddingEnd + mMarginStart,bottom);
paint.setColor(mBackgroundColor);
canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, mCornerRadius, mCornerRadius, paint);
paint.setColor(mTextColor);
canvas.drawText(text, start, end, x + mMarginStart, y + (YourValue), paint);
}

Here give the value in (YourValue, lets say 11)